# How to make a program that links a word to a list containing the files that have that word in them (given a specific directory)

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I'm learning Python in my free time using a book I bought on Amazon, at the end of each chapter there are a couple of exercises to use what you just learned.
One of these exercises was about writing a program that, given a directory, creates a dictionary that has:

- as keys the words contained in the text files of the directory
- as values lists that contain all the files that have that particular word

this in what I came up with:

```
import re
import os


directory = input("what's the directory?")
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    for file in directory:
        with open(file) as doc:
            r_doc = doc.read()
            parole = re.split(r"\W+",r_doc.lower())      #create a list of all the words in the text using as a division non-alphanumeric elements
            parola = list(set(parole))                   #get a list that contains each word only once

        for i in parola:
            contenenti = []
            if i in r_doc:
                contenenti.append(r_doc)
        kseq = i
        vseq = contenenti
        dizionario = dict(zip(kseq,vseq))
```

I keep getting the error :"no such file or directory"
Is there a problem just with the directory or the code in completely wrong?
thank you in advance to anyone who will answer

Comment: What do you give as input?

Comment: Focus your attention on the specific error. You'll get a traceback with the error, please include it as an edit in your question.

Comment: please fix your indentation - after `with open(file) as doc:`

Comment: Why do you want the second `for` loop - `for file in directory:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`directory` is a string. You redefine `file` from a file in a dir to a character in a string

```
directory = input("what's the directory?")   # a string
for file in os.listdir(directory):      # some files
    for file in directory:              # file redefined as character iterator in string
        with open(file) as doc:         # using the character from directory here
                                        # which does not exist on your harddrive
```

Solution: remove `for file in directory:`

Comment: @roganjosh HE used file twice, thats the reason for his error, he is overwriting his "correct" file with the iteration over the `dictionary` string. that character does not exist as file on his system

Comment: @roganjosh Felt I was unclear and corrected myself ;)

Comment: thank you so much! the problem is solved but I got another error: now when I open the file I get a bunch of strange symbols and not the text it actually contained, do I have to use some encode/decode function? I'm sorry to bother all of you with questions that could be silly for you but I can't make this program work even if I have been trying all day.

Comment: @YurijPettinari If you can use notepad to open the file in question and see text-only, python should read it fine. If it is a .doc(x) file, its MicrosoftWord - you can not simply open those as text and see what you see in MSWord - theres binary and formattingdata interleaved with the text you see when opening it with word. Search SO for "python read text" + the file extension you are trying to open. Executables or dlls or other filetypes are no "text" either.

Comment: it was a sample .txt file I got from a random site, anyway I solved the problem, thank you so much!